# Insert Into If two queries are equals

Tags: mysql, insert, compare

Basically, here is what I would like to do:

```
IF
( 
   SELECT start FROM team WHERE teamid=0
   ==  
   SELECT end FROM team WHERE teamid=0 
)

THEN

INSERT INTO team (end) VALUES ( NOW() );
```

Of course the typo is wrong but you have the idea.

Is this even possible in MySQL ?

Comment: See INSERT SELECT syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an update statement:

```
update team
    set `end` = now()
    where `start` = `end` and teamid = 0;
```

This will set the `end` column to the current time, in rows where the `end` column equals the `start` column and the `teamid` is `0`.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, update was what I needed, thanks for pointed this out. Just a simple thing, should be " and teamid = 0 " at the end, but the logic was good. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this way then

```
declare k int;
SELECT k = 1 FROM team WHERE start = end and teamid=0
IF ( k = 1 )
THEN
INSERT INTO team (end) VALUES ( NOW() );
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I think I would never be able to understand the MySql syntax. I choosed the other answer because it was easier to understand but I will definitely try to work around the variable.